# Is there an intuitive meaning of $p - p^2$

Tags: probability

If $p$ is the probability of an event occurring, does $p - p^2$ have an intuitive meaning?

Comment: $\quad\text{ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It gives you the [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) in the amount the event will occur — roughly speaking, it tells you how predictable a trial will be.

Note that $p-p^2$ is zero when $p=0$ or $p=1$, meaning that the outcome is totally predictable in those cases, and is largest when $p=1/2$, meaning that it is as unpredictable as possible in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Since $p-p^2=p(1-p)$ it is the probability of the event occurring multiplied by the probability of it not occurring. For example if $p$ is the probability of a coin coming up heads. Then $p(1-p)$ is the probability it comes up head then tail after two throws.

Comment: Thank you, of course. I should have figured that out. It is also the variance of a binomial variable, right?

Comment: Yes, as stated in the other answer, it is the variance of the binomial distribution (when $n=1$)

Comment: @smcc Also known as the Bernoulli distribution (a Binomial being a sum of independent and identically distributed Bernoullis).